# Winforms move focus to next control in usercontrol

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to move focus in `UserControl` controls?  Check attachment first.
I have put controls in `TableLayout` and set `**TabIndex**` all work good. But when focus come to usercontrol `Drzave, Postanski br., Grad and Adrese` he skip usercontrol.

So in `TableLayout ROW` i first put `Panel` and in that panel i put `UserControl`.
Problem is becouse move to next control focus not work if next control is in the panel.

**What i try:**

All my controls have abstract base class and all override `OnKeyUp` event. I change `TAB` with `Enter`

```
protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
    }
}
```

So all my controls override this event and all work good.

In `usercontrol` i create property to try access on control and set focus from parent form.

```
  public BaseComboBox Drzava
    {
        get { return this.drzaveComboBox.Drzave; }
        set { this.drzaveComboBox.Drzave = value; }
    }
```

Also i create `LEAVE` event on `TextBox Rabat`. When user leave rabat text box i try manualy to set focus in usercontrol drzava.

```
  private void rabatTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.adreseGroupedUC1.Drzava.Focus(); // select();
        }
```

This both case what i try not working.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [SelectNextControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol)?

Comment: Read [Control.TabStop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in the properties tab for your panel object (see image below). Give the panel an index after the last input field above it, and give the first input field within the panel the same index. Example index order:

inputfield 1 = 0,
inputfield 2 = 1,

Panel = 2,

inputfield 3 in panel = 2,
inputfield 4 in panel = 3,

inputfield 2 = 4,

Also change the **panel's TabStop property to true**. This will force the TAB to continue in the correct order.

[image]

Comment: If you read question you will be TabIndex is already used. if you see GIF picture you will see TabIndex already used...

Comment: @Ivan Have you given the same tab order to the panel and the inputfield in the panel? And the use of TabStop on the panel?

Comment: @Ivan And remove any code that tried to resolve the issue. I've tested this method and it works fine with just the property settings.